# Github merge request to prevent merge conflicts

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

Hi I have a master branch and I want to merge two branches in it . like   1. feature-1   2.feature-2  3. feature-3.

Firstly I create feature-1 branch  and created it from **master** and created a merge request which is pending .

Now I want to work in feature-2 , so should I create it from master or feature-1 ?

Comment: "I want to merge two branches in it . like 1. feature-1 2.feature-2 3. feature-3" Maybe my arithmetic is faulty but it seems to me that that's _three_ branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to work in feature-2 , so should I create it from master or feature-1 ?

From `master`. All branches should emanate from the branch to which they will later be merged. Obviously they don't *have* to be — it's not a magical hard and fast rule — but it's a good convention to follow, as it will reduce complexity later on.

If `feature-1` gets merged into `master` while you are still working on `feature-2` and you would like to update `feature-2` to acquire the aspects of `feature-1` that got merged in, you can rebase `feature-2` onto `master` (or merge `master` into `feature-2`, though I don't like that approach so much).

But I also want to push back against the presupposition built into your question, namely, you seem to think that conflicts are something that is to be prevented. This is *wrong*. Merge conflicts are *not bad*. I wish they had named this something else; I call them "manual merges", as opposed to what `git merge` tries to do autonomously, which is "automatic merges". Sometimes a purely automatic merge is impossible, so you have to give git an assist with a manual merge. That's all. It's still a merge and nothing went wrong. It's normal and you should try not to cringe at the prospect.

Comment: If I want some code of  feature-1  but its still not merged in master then ?

Comment: Don't want that. Feature branches should be effectively independent of one another, because in the standardized pull-request workflow, you cannot know when and in what order the outstanding pull requests will be merged. You can "borrow" a commit from feature 1 into feature 2 by cherry picking that commit, if you really have to.

Comment: last question : actually I already took created  feature-2  from feature-1. what should I do now ? should I continue or delete feature-2 and create it  again  from master?

Comment: Sorry, that's a completely different question from the question you asked in the Question box. I've given an answer to _the question you asked_. You can accept it or not, but you don't get to change it and perpetuate the comments.